# Change emoji size like Whatsup

Tags: java, android

how can I change the emoji sizes like in messaging apps? If there is only one emoji sent in a message then it's bigger, if there are two they are smaller, if they are sent inline with the text then it's normal text size.

Is there any library that can help to do this? or how can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

The emojis themselfs don't change.
Whatsapp just changes the font-size of the message.